# Validating Regex US ZIP CODE with constraints in Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that follows these constraints:

- Exactly 5 digits
- Sometimes, but not always, followed by a dash with 4 more digits
- Zip code needs to be preceded by at least one whitespace
- Cannot be at the start of a text

I've arrived at this but it's not giving me the output I want:

```
r"^[A-Za-z].*\s.*\d{5}(?:[-\s]\d{4})?$"
```

Comment: Can you provide your input and expected output?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with A-Za-z.  You certainly did not mention anything about that in your requirements.  Make sure you really understand the Regex language well.

Comment: Why do you start with `[A-Za-z]`? Did you look at [`re` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)?

Comment: In general to troubleshoot a regex, take stuff out of it until it starts matching.  Then gradually add stuff to it.  That way you know exactly what problem to focus on.

Comment: My thinking was that [A-Za-z] would mean that the ZIP code cannot be at the start of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
(?<=[ \t])((?:\d{5}(?=[^\d-]|$))|(?:\d{5}-\d{4}(?=[^\d-]|$)))
```

[Demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/xSbHdE/1/)

Comment: yep that works @dawg. That whole first half I wouldn't have figured out myself. Thanks!!